# Insert mutiple CSV files in multiple columns

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, multiple-columns

[Dategridview of my list of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhgq1.png)

How could I add 3 column of values of Column 5 -10 from the 3 comma-separated-values (csv) files at one go

> say : C:\FYP\2000data\Z1ert00000.cvs,
>
> C:\FYP\2000data\Z1ert00001.cvs and
>
> C:\FYP\2000data\Z1ert00002.cvs

when I click the add/import button?

> P.S : I have 2000 cvs files to insert to the DatagridView. Is there
>   any other easier way too ? Means I will have 2000 columns appearing in
>   the Datagridview.

```
 private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var parsedData = new List<string[]>();
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(txtFilename.Text))  // 
      {
          string line;
          while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
              string[] row = line.Split(',');
              parsedData.Add(row);
          }

      }
      dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
          var sb = new StringBuilder(parsedData[0][i]);
          dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = sb.ToString();
      }
      foreach (string[] row in parsedData)
      {
          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
      }
      for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
      {
          dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[0]);  // first 5 rows of the data
      }

      dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(dataGridView1.Columns[0]); // remove the first column 

 }
```

These are the codes to import only one csv file

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Can you post the code you're using at the moment?

Comment: Sorry for the messy codings. I'm new here :/

Comment: Just add it in the question and format it as code

Answer (score 0):

#### What you're trying to achieve

You're saying you have 2000 files you'd like to see on the datagridview. I find it hard to believe that this is what you realy want as it will become

1. pretty slow on the initial load (parsing 2000 files)
2. Unreadable... who scrolls through 2000 columns?

So I think you should first consider what it is you want to do with the information in these csv files. Think about UI design. Perhaps create a search function?

#### Working with large data

If these are static files, I would propose to import all these csv files into a database so you have easy access to them and can use an ORM model in your program. Take a look at Entity Framework.
Importing these files into a SQL database can be as easy as this:

```
BULK INSERT SchoolsTemp
FROM 'C:\CSVData\Schools.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

Or use any of the already available [tutorials out there](https://www.google.be/webhp?q=insert%20csv%20into%20sql).

Then you can start thinking about paging the data you're getting out and how to visualize them so the data becomes useful.

Hope this helps.